# WriteLn in console after create thread print wrong

Tags: multithreading, console, pascal, lazarus

I have a problem with text what I see in my console after use writeLn.

My code:

```
(...)

procedure TTestApp.Run;
var
  MyThread:TMyThread;
begin

    writeLn('Start new program');

    writeLn('Start new thread');

    MyThread:=TMyThread.Create;

    sleep(1000);

    writeLn('Next part of program');

    end;


var
  TestApp: TTestApp;
begin

  TestApp := TTestApp.Create;
  TestApp.Run;
  TestApp.Free;
end.
```

After use this code i didnt get in my console what I expected. I get:

```
Start new program.
Start new thread
New thread started
Start new thread
```

but I expected:

```
Start new program.
Start new thread
New thread started
Next part of program.
```

MyThread just use writeLn and print "New thread started":

```
 TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
      procedure Execute; override;
      public
          constructor Create;
  end;

    constructor TMyThread.Create;
    begin
        inherited Create(false);
    end;


procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
quit:boolean; 
begin
      FreeOnTerminate := False;

      writeLn('New thread started');

      quit:=false;
      repeat
      //some infinite stuff
      until quit;       

end;
```

Can you help me? What I do wrong?

It looks like after create new thread I cant print on console from TestApp.Run

Comment: Since you don't show all of your code, it is hard to guess what is going on. FPK tried to reconstruct the entire code from what you posted, and he/she gets the same as I get in Delphi and what you expected. Is this "infinite stuff" perhaps (directly or indirectly) starting a new thread?

Comment: Yes, this "infinite stuff" starting a new thread.

Comment: Then why do you wonder? Note that nothing shows when the loop quits.

Comment: After create new thread should print in console 'Next part of program' but didin't.
In "infinite stuff" I am starting new thread but this is diferent thread and dont print anything in console.

Comment: As said in my answer: please post a complete example so we can figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Obviously, the code that writes `Start new thread`is re-entered somehow (or the string is duplicated), so something is terribly amiss, and ***it is not in the code we can see here***. So, as you were asked before, please post a minimal, complete and verifiable example that exhibits the behaviour you observed.

Comment: You didn't *post full code*, because the code you posted won't compile with `(...)` as the first line. Put **real code** that we can copy/paste and **compile** that will demonstrate the problem.If you're not willing to put the effort into your question to provide the details, why should we want to put effort into trying to help you?

Comment: `WriteLn` is not Thread-Safe, so you need to a `CriticalSection` for using `WriteLn` in some threads

Answer (score 2):

With some guessing I made a compiling example, but it works as expected with my setup.

So there are two possibilities:

- The particular version of Lazarus you are using has a bug.
- The code you compiled, is different from what I guessed. So please post a complete compiling example to rule this out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try install some nowe version.

Comment: I'd rather take a good look at my code. There seem to be things going on that you don't show, and which could cause the weird effects you see.

Comment: I'm sure this is in my code but I cant find this ;)

Comment: @Mlody87: If you can't find it and you have the code in front of you, how do you expect **us** to find it when we don't have all the code? Edit your question, provide a full MCVE that we can use, and we can probably help.

Comment: Works for me FPC 3.0.0 win32

Comment: And you see?
`Start new program.
Start new thread
New thread started
Starting working threads
Done
Next part of program.`