# Cancel ReadLn input reading

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I'm running a constant loop of ReadLn to get command input. But when it comes to multithreading, I get an issue:

```
var command: string;

function ThreadTest(p: pointer) : ptrint;
begin
  Delay(500);
  WriteLn('THREAD TEST');
end;  
{...}
BeginThread(@ThreadTest); 
ReadLn(command);
```

'THREAD TEST' is written in the input field.

Is there any way to prevent this? I don't want to wait for the thread to finish to call ReadLn. Do I have to rewrite ReadLn using ReadKey? I'm using FreePascal with Crt and Windows.

**EDIT**: I need to write 'THREAD TEST' as a new line and move the ReadLn down 1 tcrtcoord, so 'THREAD TEST' is displayed properly. WriteLn works perfectly and as intended, unless called while ReadLn is in process.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect or want?

Comment: I need to write 'THREAD TEST' as a new line and move the ReadLn input field down 1 tcrtcoord, so 'THREAD TEST' is displayed properly. Losing the input isn't an issue for now at least.

Comment: Are you sure it is ok to call WriteLn from a thread (apart from the app's main one)?

Comment: I need it to allow asynchronous procedures (writing a command-based language), so as long as ReadLn isn't called everything is fine. Except that I actually need to call ReadLn after compiling the main thread.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814715/writeln-in-console-after-create-thread-print-wrong?  I am not aware of anything which says that background threads are safe to use WriteLn in FPC.

Comment: WriteLn works perfectly and as intended, unless called while ReadLn is in process. If there are any inconveniences with it, I'll deal with them. But the question isn't about using WriteLn, it's about cancelling/pausing ReadLn.

Comment: Well, if you are calling WriteLn from a not-threadsafe situation, it may cause ReadLn to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: If you want synchronization between various writing to the console, you need to implement it.

Comment: I guess there's no other choice for me